Local Lipschitz continuity of signature map $S:C^{1-\text{var}}([0,T],\mathbb{R}^d) \to \mathcal{H}$
Just came across the claim that the signature map (between path space and tensor space) is locally Lipschitz continuous with respect to the $1-$variation norm (see section A.2.1).
More specifically, let $C^{1-\text{var}}([0,T],\mathbb{R}^d)$ denote the usual space of bounded variation paths and let $\mathcal{H} \subset T((\mathbb{R}^d))$ be the subset of the extended tensor algebra with finite $l_2-$norm, which is known to be a Hilbert space. Then, the authors claim that for every $M>0$ there exists a constant $C(M,T)$ such that for all $X,Y \in C^{1-\text{var}}([0,T],\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $\| X\|_{1-\text{var}},\| Y\|_{1-\text{var}} \leq M$, we have
$$\| S(X) - S(Y)\|_{\mathcal{H}} \leq C(M,T) \|X - Y\|_{1\text{-var}},$$
where as usual $S(X)$ denotes the full signature of the path $X$. Apparently this should follow directly from Lyons' extension theorem (the authors cite Thm 3.1.3 in  System control and rough paths), but I'm not seeing how exactly... Also I would expect to see an upper bound of the form $O( e^{\|X-Y\|_{1\text{-var}}})$, considering that the estimates obtained for the continuity of Lyons' extension are for each tensor level.
Can anyone shed some light on this? Is there some other reference for the local Lipschitzness of the signature map? I'm aware that in the book by Friz and Victoir, the authors prove local Lipschitzness of the truncated signature as a map between path spaces. But that's not exactly what the estimate above is saying. Any help will be much appreciated!
